# Not Able to Launch Activity using intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a button initialized

```
button1= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Tn the OnClick() function I have

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

My New Activity's name is MainActivity2 in the Manifest file

```
  <activity
            android:name="com.example.intent.MainActivity2"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_activity2" >
        </activity>
```

But the 2nd activity never launches

Please help.

**Activity 1**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button button1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button1= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    }


    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }


}
```

**XML LAYOUT**

```
<activity
            android:name="com.example.intent.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.intent.MainActivity2"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_activity2" >
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Comment: please add your full first activity code and xml layout

Comment: Are you sure that the `onClick` method is even called?

Comment: post your error information.

Comment: put All code of your Activity & manifest file & xml. without see these two file how we solve yout isssue??

Comment: **"never launces"** did you try to find the reason behind it.. Like if ther was an error..? or even debugging to know if **onClick** got called..

Comment: Got it... dint set listener to button ...

Comment: I really can't understand how questions like that get dozends of answers and upvotes, whereas this is completely trivial and can be looked up in at least 1000 tutorials if the guy who questioned just had searched a bit. It's a shame what happened with stackoverflow. Users just don't want reputation and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

You did not register the `onClick` event to the button.

**From:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button button1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button1= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    }
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**To:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button button1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button1= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

to

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
    startActivity(intent);
   }
};
```

You should set the onClicklistener to the button

Comment: Ya.. just realized.. That.

Comment: This is a correct way to solve it, but it doesn't "answer" to the question. In my opinion the implemented version is more consistent, and more beautiful to look at, when it comes to code structure.

Answer (score 0):

buddy you just need to chage one word from your code..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button button1;

public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (R.id.button1) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    }
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button1= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

this will deeinitely work....

Comment: How would this help him? The `onClick` is not triggered. So the `Intent` is never called.

Comment: @TobiasMoeThorstensen ya forgot that to write...updated the code